# How to make images visible in when lazy loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, lazy-loading

I am trying to "lazy load" a bunch of pictures using jquery but they don't appear on the screen when loading the page. I know xhtml, basic js and css. I have seen many different solutions to "lazy load" but I haven't been able to make any of them work.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/master/jquery.lazyload.min.js"></script>  
<body>
    <img data-original="image.jpg"  width="640" height="480" class="lazy">
    <img data-original="image.jpg"  width="640" height="480" class="lazy">
    <img data-original="image.jpg"  width="640" height="480" class="lazy">
    <img data-original="image.jpg"  width="640" height="480" class="lazy">
    <img data-original="image.jpg"  width="640" height="480" class="lazy">
    <img data-original="image.jpg"  width="640" height="480" class="lazy">
  <script>$("img.lazy").lazyload();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is: what is it that I am doing wrong so that when I load the page the file "image.jpg" doesn't appear.

Comment: Are you using your own source or directly linking from github?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the source from GitHub, and linking it directly to your project, an error will be thrown:

> Refused to execute script from '`https://raw.github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/master/jquery.lazyload.min.js`' because its MIME type (`'text/plain'`) is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Please make sure you have a local copy and execute it locally.

Checked locally and it executes well! `:)` The code you are using is right, other than **hot-linking** the JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast! If I understood correctly,I have to place the JavaScript on a separate file (e.g. lazy.js) and link it to the html file via "<script type="text/javascript" src="lazy.js">, right? Thanks again!